# Create background video based on screen width

Tags: background, html5-video

I would like to create a background video element based on the width of my viewport. I've tried this so far but unfortunately didn't have success.

```html
        <script>
    if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            div.class = 'fullsize-video-bg w-background-video w-background-video-atom';
                    div.data-poster-url = 'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/6276866ad0b6dfd92c709261_video-mobile-poster-00001.jpg';
                    div.data-video-urls = 'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/6276866ad0b6dfd92c709261_video-mobile-transcode.mp4,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/6276866ad0b6dfd92c709261_video-mobile-transcode.webm';
            div.data-autoplay = 'true';
            div.data-loop = 'true';
            div.data-wf-ignore = 'true';
            div.innerHTML = '<video id="a5555903-b716-d8eb-3a03-360ccf397ab7-video" autoplay="" loop="" style="background-image:url(&quot;https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/6276866ad0b6dfd92c709261_video-mobile-poster-00001.jpg&quot;)" muted="" playsinline="" data-wf-ignore="true" data-object-fit="cover"><source src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/6276866ad0b6dfd92c709261_video-mobile-transcode.mp4" data-wf-ignore="true"><source src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/6276866ad0b6dfd92c709261_video-mobile-transcode.webm" data-wf-ignore="true"></video>';
            document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    else {
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            div.class = 'fullsize-video-bg w-background-video w-background-video-atom';
                    div.data-poster-url = 'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/627686bfbd3c578b1dd34dbb_video-desktop-poster-00001.jpg';
                    div.data-video-urls = 'https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/627686bfbd3c578b1dd34dbb_video-desktop-transcode.mp4,https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/627686bfbd3c578b1dd34dbb_video-desktop-transcode.webm';
            div.data-autoplay = 'true';
            div.data-loop = 'true';
            div.data-wf-ignore = 'true';
            div.innerHTML = '<video id="a5555903-b716-d8eb-3a03-360ccf397ab7-video" autoplay="" loop="" style="background-image:url(&quot;https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/627686bfbd3c578b1dd34dbb_video-desktop-poster-00001.jpg&quot;)" muted="" playsinline="" data-wf-ignore="true" data-object-fit="cover"><source src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/627686bfbd3c578b1dd34dbb_video-desktop-transcode.mp4" data-wf-ignore="true"><source src="https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/618427c454b0a519900b9198/627686bfbd3c578b1dd34dbb_video-desktop-transcode.webm" data-wf-ignore="true"></video>';
            document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
    </script>
```

If you have any idea how to make this work, I would be very thankful!

Best
Julian

Comment: _"I've tried this so far but unfortunately didn't have success."_ How is it not working? Are you saying the If/Else check doesn't happen? Did you check the value of `$(window).width()` via **alert** or **console.log**?

Comment: Or maybe you mean the div did not contain the innerHTML contents (_eg:_ no video tag was created)? It's not obvious what's not working.